# Удалить блок при нажатии на кнопку в нём

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок. В нём есть имейдж хрестика. При нажатии блок юолжен удалятсья. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста ваш html и css

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let button = document.querySelector(.button) // объявление значения button для элемента css класса .button
let div = document.querySelector(.div) // объявление значения div для всех элементов класса div (используйте уникальный ксс класс для div вашего блока)

button.addEventListener('click', function() { // добавление eventListener элементу, прописанному в значении button, работающий при клике на него
div.style.display = 'none'; // при клике поменять класс css display значения div на none
})
```